# Lookup fields or Choice fields?

Tags: infopath

I have a number of fields that could either be lookup or choice fields and I don't know which to use.  I heard using Lookup was "more sophisticated" but I don't see how it is very useful when I have to have more fields come back from the list than just Title and ID. I have to use complex filters that mean a straight Lookup doesn't work well. Does anyone have more advice for me to follow here?

InfoPath 2010 used in SharePoint 2010 list.

Comment: Is the information for this field going to be a static list of values or one that you need to modify on a regular basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you possible share a sample of what these "complex filters" are?

In general, here is what I use to determine if its going to be a CHOICE or a LOOKUP.

If the data I am going to store in the field is only limited to a few number of choices AND / OR the data is not too important in itself, then I use a CHOICE field. For the simplicity.

However, if the data can be selected from a LARGE amount of choices that would need a good maintainability AND / OR the data in itself is relevant, then I would use a LOOKUP field so I can create a list for the list of valid choices as well as enter metadata regarding each record I enter.